# This site can’t be reached after adding custom domain

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I’ve added a custom domain to my site (from bluehost). I’ve set the A record in bluehost to 104.198.14.52 (netlify load balancer). I’ve also set the CNAME for www host record to carlrippon.com:

[image]

In the netlify domains settings page the DNS appears to have resolved:

[image]

However, when I browse to http://carlrippon.com/ I get “This site can’t be reached. carlrippon.com’s server IP address could not be found.”:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I can get to https://carlrippon.com/ just fine here. I'd suspect you have a cached "no such domain" response and that in a couple of hours it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this - the CNAME in bluehost needed to point to carlrippon.netlify.com.